# How watch the content of a TextAngular text editor for addition/deletion of element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, addeventlistener, watch

I've successfully customized a *textangular* module to add a `glossify` button using the following code :

```js
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('ReaderCtrl', ['$scope', '$document', '$log', function ($scope, $document, $log) {
        $scope.glossList = [];
    }])
    .config(function($provide){
        $provide.decorator('taOptions', ['$delegate', function(taOptions){
            taOptions.toolbar = [
                ['gloss', 'bold', 'italics', 'redo', 'undo'],
            ];
            return taOptions; // whatever you return will be the taOptions
        }]);
        $provide.decorator('taOptions', ['taRegisterTool', '$delegate', '$log', function(taRegisterTool, taOptions, $log){
            taRegisterTool('gloss', {
                buttontext: "Gloss",
                action: function(e, elt, editorScope){
                    var selectedText = window.getSelection();
                    var  glossTag = '<strong class="gloss">'+ selectedText +'</strong>';
                    return this.$editor().wrapSelection('insertHTML', glossTag, true);
                },
                activeState: function(commonElement) {// state is detected by the HTML class 'gloss'
                    if(commonElement) return commonElement[0].className === 'gloss';
                    return false;
                },
            });
            return taOptions;
        }]);
    });
```

### Goal

I want to watch the content of the text editor for addition/deletion of marked text (i.e. text wrapper in `<strong class="gloss">…</strong>`).

Then dynamically update a list in the scope  (e.g. `$scope.glossList`). In order to run HTTP requests against  my REST API and create new element in my page.

### Question

**[See Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/In2UFGrKxvUSNZoUkdNU?p=preview)**

First, How do I watch for addition/deletion of elements in the editor content ?